# Scanner using delimiter but not recognizing the integer after it

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter, java-io, inputmismatchexception

I can't seem to find the issue in my code and was wondering if you wonderful people on here would be willing to help me out. My professor is requiring us to create a 2-D array from information pulled from a file she provided us. Using the Scanner and File class we should be able to accomplish this, however, I have hit a speed bump. My scanner is not recognizing the integer after the delimiter I have set for it. Here is the file she provides us with.

```
5x7
o,2,3
7,1,3
7,1,1
X,4,2
```

This info is separated by newlines where there are spaces in the blockquote.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Battlefield {

// Use the FILL_CHAR for a space that contains no creature.
// Use these chars for creatures so that your code will pass
// the tests used for evaluating your program.
public final char FILL_CHAR = '-';
public final char OGRE      = 'o';
public final char CENTAUR   = '7';
public final char DRAGON    = 'X';

private char[][] field;

public Battlefield(String fn) {
    try {
    // You write code here.
    // Read a file and initialize the field.
    // The name of the file is passed in from the driver.
    // Keep all the file reading stuff in the try/catch block
    // to make file exceptions easier to deal with.
    File battlefield = new File(fn);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(battlefield);
    scan.useDelimiter("x");
    int row = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(row);
    System.out.println(scan.next());
    System.out.println(scan.hasNextInt());
    int column = scan.nextInt();
    char[][] field = new char[row][column];

    /**
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(battlefield);
    scan2.useDelimiter(",");
    /**
    field[scan2.nextInt()][scan2.nextInt()] = OGRE;
    field[scan2.nextInt()][scan2.nextInt()] = CENTAUR;
    field[scan2.nextInt()][scan2.nextInt()] = CENTAUR;
    field[scan2.nextInt()][scan2.nextInt()] = DRAGON;
    **/
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

And my main method/driver class:

```
public class BattlefieldDrv {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Battlefield battlefieldOne = new Battlefield("1field.dat");
    System.out.println(battlefieldOne.toString());
}
}
```

Here is my stack trace:

```
> 5
  7
  o,2,3
  7,1,3
  7,1,1
  X,4,2
false
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Battlefield.<init>(Battlefield.java:38)
    at BattlefieldDrv.main(BattlefieldDrv.java:15)
```

Thank you for any help or insight you have!

Comment: Um, the file you listed does not appear to actually use "x" as a delimiter.  Why did you do that?

Comment: @markspace the file's first line is 5x7 so I used "x" as a delimiter to get past the x and to the next integer which is 7.

Comment: You show a ">" and a space in front of those two numbers.  What happens to them?

Comment: Sorry, those are not included in the file. I edited it. @markspace

Comment: OK so now how about the character after the 7?

Comment: There is no character after the 7 in the file unless you would like to count "\n" I guess. @markspace

Comment: I would count the "\n", because otherwise the Scanner won't be able to read past it.

Comment: If you use 'x' as a delimiter, you won't get it back from the `Scanner` with `next() `.

Comment: @markspace adding \n to the delimiter list made it so I got nothing with my scanner, not even the 5 I can get without having \n in the delimiter list.

Comment: @daniu I do not need the x, only the 5 and 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's step through this code.

```
scan.useDelimiter("x");
int row = scan.nextInt();
```

5 is read into `row`.

```
System.out.println(row);
```

5 is printed.

```
System.out.println(scan.next());
```

The *rest of the file* is read and printed, because that's what comes after the `x`.

```
System.out.println(scan.hasNextInt());
```

There's nothing left to read, so the `NoSuchElementException` is thrown here.

You need to make the scanner also accept newlines as delimiter; you can do that by using

```
scan.useDelimiter("(x|\\s)");
```

(The `\\s` is the pattern for "any whitespace").

As a side note, it's good practice to use the `try-with-resources`-construct:

```
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(Paths.get("1field.dat"))) {
    scan.useDelimiter(...);
    ...
} catch (IOException e) {
```

This will result in your file resource being closed automatically.